# Intuitive explanation of generic extension

Tags: set-theory, intuition, model-theory

I am attempting to understand cohen's proof by forcing that the continuum hypotheses is independent of ZFC . However,I am having trouble understanding intuitively the concept of a generic extension of a model. Can anyone give me an intuitive explanation (with examples if possible)?. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you talking about generic extensions in the sense of set theory? I'm not familiar with a use of that term in the context of model theory in particular.

Comment: I came across generic extensions in the context of forcing, which uses generic extensions of models of ZFC. So I thought they would be related to model theory as well as set theory.

Comment: I don't think there is a direct generalization of the notion of forcing extensions to arbitrary theories. There are some notions in model theory that one could say are about 'generic' structures (such as Fraïssé limits and existentially closed models), but they're only indirectly related to forcing.

Comment: For me, forcing construction adds a 'generic' object that is usually 'random' in the sense that they are not specified by 'dense properties' of the ground model. I do not think my rough description captures every possible essence of forcing, however, but I wish it would be helpful to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about set theory, the main theorem is that $V[G]$ is the minimal model of set theory containing $V$ with $G$ as an element.

More precisely, if $V\models \mathsf{ZFC}$ is a transitive model, $\mathbb{P}\in V$ is a poset, and $G$ (usually not in $V$) is $\mathbb{P}$-generic over $V$, then

1. $V[G]\models\mathsf{ZFC}$,
2. $V[G]$ is transitive with $V\subseteq V[G]$, $G\in V[G]$, and
3. If $M\models\mathsf{ZFC}$ is transitive with $V\subseteq M$ and $G\in M$, $V[G]\subseteq M$.

The elements of the generic extension come from so-called $\mathbb{P}$-names.  To give some context, consider the constructible universe $L$ defined in stages where we take $\{\in\}$-definable subsets at each stage.  There's a notion of $L[x]$ where we take $\{\in,x\}$-definable subsets at each stage.  In essence, we allow ourselves ask questions about membership in $x$.  If $x\subseteq \mathbb{P}$ for some $\mathbb{P}\in L$, then $x\in L[x]$ and we basically consider everything constructible from $x$ in the same way we construct the elements of $L$.

This all works out nicely for $L$, which has a nice definition. But how should we generalize this to such an arbitrary $V$?  Well the idea is that we consider all sorts of potential constructions that $V$ can carry out.  Then when we have access to $V[G]$, we just thin out these potential constructions by our (outside of $V$) access to $G$.  These potential constructions are just sets tagged with members of our poset $\mathbb{P}$.  Once we know what's in $G$, we can include the elements tagged with things in $G$ and throw out the members tagged with things not in $G$.  For example, if $G=\{p\}$, $\{\langle 0,p\rangle ,\langle 1,q\rangle \}$ would be thinned out to just $\{0\}$.  If $G=\{p,q\}$, the same set would be thinned out to $\{0,1\}$.

So this is basically the setup: we iteratively form these potential constructions and then with access to $G$, we thing things out and end up with $V[G]$:

- $V_0^{\mathbb{P}}=\emptyset$
- $V_{\alpha + 1}^{\mathbb{P}}$ is the set of potential constructions using elements of $V_{\alpha}^{\mathbb{P}}$, i.e. $V_{\alpha + 1}^{\mathbb{P}}=\mathcal{P}(V_{\alpha}^{\mathbb{P}}\times \mathbb{P})$
  = $V_{\alpha}^{\mathbb{P}}=\bigcup_{\xi<\alpha}V_{\xi}^{\mathbb{P}}$ for limit $\alpha$.

As described above, we thin these constructions our (or *interpret*) these names by setting
$$\tau_G=\{\sigma_G:\langle \sigma,p\rangle\in \tau\text{ for some }p\in G\}\text{.}$$
Then we take
$$V[G]=\{\tau_G:\tau\in V^{\mathbb{P}}=\bigcup_{\alpha\in\mathrm{Ord}}V_\alpha^{\mathbb{P}}\}$$
Why exactly does this work?  For example, how do we know $G\in V[G]$?  It's easy to see that $\tau = \{\langle p,p\rangle:p\in\mathbb{P}\}$ gives $\tau_G=G$.  How do we know $V\subseteq V[G]$?  One can show that there are *canonical* names for $x\in V$ basically just by iteratively setting $\check \emptyset = \emptyset$, and
$$\check x = \{\langle \check y, p\rangle:y\in x\text{ and }p\in\mathbb{P}\}\text{.}$$
It's not too difficult to show that this works.

Again, the main idea is that $V[G]$ is what $V$ would look like if it had access to $G$ because we are basing $V[G]$ on what constructions $V$ allows.